# Android: Code seems correct but list will not appear

Tags: android, listview

I am having an issue where my list absolutely refuses to render.

This is my first activity that has a button that leads to the activity that should render the list. There is a subsequent xml that has the onClick method bound to the openHistory method.

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private static final String FILE_NAME = "books.txt";
public static BookList bookList = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);
    bookList = new BookList(FILE_NAME, this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    bookList.writeToFile(this);
    this.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);
}

public void openHistory(View v){
    Intent histIntent = new Intent(this, HistoryActivity.class);

    this.startActivity(histIntent);
}
}
```

And this is the activity that should render the list.

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history_activity);
    ListView history = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    temp.add("dog");
    temp.add("cat");
    temp.add("fish");
    temp.add("dog");
    temp.add("cat");
    temp.add("fish");
    temp.add("dog");
    temp.add("cat");
    temp.add("fish");
    temp.add("dog");
    temp.add("cat");
    temp.add("fish");
    temp.add("dog");
    temp.add("cat");
    temp.add("fish");
    temp.add("dog");
    temp.add("cat");
    temp.add("fish");
    temp.add("dog");
    temp.add("cat");
    temp.add("fish");

    ArrayAdapter historyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp);

    history.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.history_activity);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    this.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}
}
```

I tried searching through several other posts (and even other websites). My code is, at the very least, syntactically correct, but I simply cannot find the error.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ListView` is not showing anything because you re-inflated the `history_activity.xml` in your `onResume` method which just overlapes the previous inflated view in `onCreate`. This is because `onResume` is called after the `onCreate`. Just remove the `setContentView(R.layout.history_activity);` from your `onResume` and everything will start working fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a lot wrong with your code. You're unnecessary overiding functions and

1) not adding functionality

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
```

}

2) setting the view in onResume. onCreate is enough

3) resetting the view. see point 3

4) calling this.finish(); in onDestroy... why?

you should start by fixing this

Comment: I was under the assumption that you had to call finish when going back to the previous activity. Does onDestroy already do that?

Comment: the back button on your phone will close the current activity. There is no need to explicitly call the finish(); method

Comment: Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html